# dynamic drop down with cakephp and Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu, input, cakephp-2.2

Hi all want to generate a dynamic drop down for Cities , as per the selection of country in cakephp 2.2 app. I am quite new to cakephp.Moreover i hardly find any tutorial for they are mostly for 1.3 or 1.2 version. I am having Drop down menus for country and city in Profile add view. Here is my code in the countries Controller though :

```
  public function citylist() {
         $this->layout=false;
         Configure::write('debug', 0);
         if($this->request->is('ajax')){    
        $country=$this->Country->read(null, $this->request['url']['country_id']);
        $code=$country['Country']['country_code'];
        $cities=$this->Country->City->find('list',array('conditions' =>array('City.country_code' => $code),'recursive' => -1,'fields' => array('id', 'name')));
        $this->set('cities',$cities);
}}
```

and my jquery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ProfileCountryId').live('change', function() {
if($(this).val().length != 0) {
  $.getJSON('/crush/countries/citylist',
              {country_id: $(this).val()},
              function(cities) {
                if(cities !== null) {
                  populateCityList(cities);
                }
    });
  }
});
});

      function populateCityList(cities) {
var options = '';

$.each(cities, function(index, city) {
options += '<option value="' + index + '">' + city + '</option>';
});
$('#ProfileHomeLocation').html(options);
$('#city-list').show();
}
```

I tried making changes but it really confusing as in diff examples i see very diff ways. 
I am not sure wether to check that request type as ajax or should i fetch the parameter value through  request->data or params[url].

I followed these two existing answers and it confused me further.
[cakephp pass dropdown value in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498560/cakephp-pass-dropdown-value-in-ajax/12004026#12004026)
[The connection was reset issue in CakePHP 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520404/the-connection-was-reset-issue-in-cakephp-2-2).

The error is strange that first time page is loaded it shows error in console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".
However if i load reload and then select the first value in the drop down. It gives error

> GET http://example.com/crush/countries/citylist?country_id=103 500
>   (Internal Server Error) jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.2.js:8240
>   jQuery.extend.ajaxjquery-1.7.2.js:7719 jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous
>   function)jquery-1.7.2.js:7245
>   jQuery.extend.getJSONjquery-1.7.2.js:7262 (anonymous
>   function)citylist.js:4 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.2.js:3332
>   jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

Don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like yours, where a dynamic drop down box is involved, I use the ajax() jQuery's method to retrieve the data and replace the whole content of the `select` element. So, instead of returning the JSON data through your AJAX call, instead you can return the full HTML `option` elements and replace the content of the `select` element with `$('myselectelement').html(data)`. This works fine.

Comment: so u mean i should add this "'<option value="' + index + '">' + city + '</option>';" stuff in within the controller and set a final string than an array !!
Will be great if u can give any exapmle or give any link , for cakephp  2.x example

Comment: It doesn't have to be CakePHP specific. Some code: `$.ajax({ url: 'myurl', data: {...}}).done(function(data){ $('#mySelectElementId').html(data); });` and the myurl should be a controller action from CakePHP that generates and the returns the html output (a string actually) using `echo $myHTMLOutput;` instead of `return $myHTMLOutput;`

Comment: Actually the Problem was with the passing of parameter value. I tried using the changed method for 2.2 version of cake, and its working fine. Though i am accepting your answer, as it gave me the idea, to pass single string, and thus i was able to find that Jquery function was working fine.